# Drupal 8 install theme in multisite environment

Tags: drupal, themes, drupal-8

I'm using Drupal in a multi-site environment. I want to create a theme only visible for this site. So I created the folder sites/site_url.be/themes/theme_name. But the theme doesn't appear on the admin/appearance.

- I have already a custom theme installed in the sites/all/themes directory, which works fine, and compared all configuration files.
- I added the css, js and templates, so it is not empty.
- Rebuild the cache several times using drush and the interface
- Changed the permissions of the directory
- I placed the theme in the sites/all/themes
- Checked the ip of the interface in the browser, so I certainly work local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in the following link: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198081/drupal-8-theme-structure-for-multi-site

If you want to check that you have configured and set-up everything correctly for your multi site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multisite-mapping-with-drupal (Drupal 8 is at the end of the page)